# Is there a site for questions about appliance operation?

Tags: discussion

[I asked this question a while ago](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/21696/856) which has reached 10,000 views, suggesting there is an audience for its information being useful.

Is there a SE that includes appliance operation in the field of questions that the above question could be migrated to and move others to if they ask appliance operation?

The above question is considered off topic due to the fact that the [Operation of major appliances or questions regarding small appliances](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is listed as off-topic in the just linked faq.

Answer (score 3):

I think most home appliances are on topic here.   We have many questions and answers about washing machines, thermostats, dryers, dish washer, and so on.   I don't see really why yours is off-topic.

[image]

Comment: The [site FAQ](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says that the operation of appliances is off-topic.  If that has changed, the FAQ should be updated.

Comment: @WilliamKF  I too was put off asking an appliance question by the FAQ.  I was hoping to get advise on how to prevent the handles on a wheelchair knocking the knobs on a propane stove that appears off topic.  I wanted to know if removing the knobs & pushing them back on constantly would damage the stove and cause a leak in a different way.  I too have been looking for site to present this question.

Comment: @WilliamKF - maybe not operation as you can RTFM but site FAQ clearly states that repairing and troubleshooting are in the remits.

Comment: @Bookaholic It's all about how you present the question. See [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/227407/42053) along with my comment and answer. I think your wheelchair question could work well on this site and induce some creative answers. Just don't be surprised if someone says to buy a stove with knobs on the horizontal plane instead of vertical and then proceed to close it as a shopping question. You would ideally present solutions which you've tried like child-safety locks.

Comment: @Bookaholic However, asking whether removing knobs and putting them back on will cause a gas leak is a good appliance maintenance question I think.